# Drawable for AndroidTv development

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-tv

I have an app developed for AndroidTv, There are some drawables that looks perfectly fine on a 43 inch TV but the same icons looks bigger on a 32 inch TV.
I have placed the drawables in drawable-tvdpi and these are vector drawables. Can someone suggest which is a correct folder to place the drawables?